# React Native Built App is closing unexpectedly

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, react-native-reanimated-v2, react-navigation-v6

Okay, I've been struggling for the last two days and this is it. I'm developing my first React Native android app using **React Native CLI** and using the following Packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-immersive": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-material-textinput": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.15",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

In the Development mode, The App works just fine and smooth. I'm developing the app without any errors. But, When I built the app for production into **aab** and **apk** files, the issue arises. If I run the app, whether via `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` or installing the app on my physical device, the app just close instantly after opening. Here's the [GitHub Repo Link](https://github.com/malinjr07/foodapp)

Note: I'm developing the app in Windows 10 with the latest Android Studio and all the latest versions of dependencies.
***Preview:*** App on Production Mode

[image: App on Production Mode]

***Preview:*** App on Development Mode

[image: App on Development Mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the app in the simulator with LogCat running and check the error message there. That should give some indication, like this it could be anything. If logcat does not automatically run in your android studio you can open a terminal and run:

> adb logcat

Comment: Okay. The problem was, in android/app/build.gradle, I've changed following values:

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

universalApk false

If I keep those unchanged, the builds work perfectly and smoothly. Can anyone please describe the reason?

Comment: Maybe you can add this to your post in some way? Would make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my **android/app/build.gradle** file. I've changed following values:

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

universalApk false

If I keep those unchanged, the builds work perfectly and smoothly. Can anyone please describe the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur due to variations from libs version incompatibilities, missing files and configuration...

In my case it was a missing key in file in:
**Info.plist**

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) requires your permission to track in order to show you more relevant ads.</string>
```

**Try looking at the simulator error log..**